# SWF file on top of another SWF-position

Tags: html, css, position, flash

I have a problem on positioning my swf file on top of another swf file. I have tried the solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ezXjx/

```
<div id="a"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf"
width="200" height="200">
<param name="movie" value="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf">
<param name="WMode" value="Transparent">
</object></div>

<div id="b"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf"
width="200" height="200">
<param name="movie" value="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf">
<param name="WMode" value="Transparent">
</object></div>



#a {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:10;
}
#b {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:20;
}
```

and I was able to position them on top of each other. The problem is, they are not EXACTLY on top of each other. The other one is slightly on the lower right.

here it is:
http://www.marinessrivera.com/trial.html

i'm a noob in these kind of things.. please help me

Comment: Don't think what you are doing is a very good idea.  There are bound to be strange rendering differences between OSes and browsers.  What purpose could you have in doing something like this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. i would just like to put a looping animation on my website. The problem is, if i only used a single swf, the whole animation process would loop, hence it would start at the beginning again. What I want is, for just some parts of the thing to loop (gears rotating, etc.) i don't want all of them to pop up again so I thought of this. If you have another solution to this other than stacking swf files, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: in this case you should set up the different loops in your swf. you can use movieclips for that. each movieclip has it's own timeline. you can put several movieclips on a flash stage.

Comment: Yes, i have set up different loops for them. The problem is when i put it on the website, after a number of seconds, everything will loop from the start which means everything will disappear then pop up again. Tell me if i did not understand your reply correctly. :)

Comment: are all these loops flash movieclip objects placed on the stage? if you do not want some of them looping you can place an action on their last frame with: `stop()`. a movieclip does not advance its playhead after that anymore.

Comment: They are graphic symbols, not movieclip symbols unfortunately. I tried to change them to movieclip but the object suddenly disappears.

Comment: Update. I tried making a movieclip symbol. However, everything still lopps back from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the css is invalid. on your example homepage it says:

```
        <style>

#homepage {
```

the #homepage style is never applied. **remove** `<style>`

at the end of the css there are also two `</style>` closing tags. remove one.

Comment: OH MY GOSH.. i feel like an idiot HAHAHAH.. thank you very much for this<3